# Flutter: Update specific screen using provider that's consumed in multiple screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a typical CRUD operation task: (List Sites, Add Site, ...)

I created a `SitesProvider`. In the same provider, I added 2 methods for add and edit. I was thinking to use the same provider in the 2 screens (`ListSites` and `AddEditSite`)

In the `ListSites` screen, it works fine. Here is the problem:

- I open the `AddSite` screen by clicking the `AddButton` in the ListSites screen
- Hit submit (did not enter data, simulating error case)
- The error gets displayed in the `ListSites` screen, not in the `AddSite` screen.

It makes sense. They both use the same provider, both screens are on the stack. It seems that the first one only consumes the state update and displays the error.

I use `MultipleProviders` approach that wraps the MaterialApp with all providers in the app.

Can we fix that without creating separate providers for each of the 2 screens?

**EDIT:**

I used `provider.removeListener` in the `ListSites` screen right before I open the AddEdit and it shows the error in the correct screen now. I still have to do some other tweaks to get it back to listen after I add. Not efficient I think but it is a step.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing that:

1. Added Another Field in the provider (stateType: list/addedit)
2. Change the type per the screen I'm currently in

   provider.stateType = UIStateType.add_edit;

await Navigator.push(context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEditSiteScreen()));

provider.stateType = UIStateType.list;

3. in build(), I check for the type

   sitesProvider = Provider.of(context);

   if (sitesProvider.stateType != UIStateType.add_edit) return Container();